# Why isn't javascript working on page that has been loaded via jQuery's .load() function?

Tags: jquery

I have a highlight form fields javascript that is linked in the head of my filea.php. I am loading another file called fileb.php which has a form in it. Now although filea.php is already referencing the external javascript with the highlight form fields code in it, the fields of the loaded page don't hightlight when selected i.e. the js isn't having any effect on the loaded page.

If I reference the external js file on the loaded page itself, it works fine. But why should I have to? For example there is no css referenced on fileb.php, however the form on that page is styled according to the style sheet that is referenced on filea.php. Why isn't it the same for scripts?

p.s. I'm loading the external js file BEFORE the .load function is performed so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Can you link to a live example?

Comment: Seconded, perhaps show us a little more code? jsFiddle is a great way to work through your errors.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: When your JavaScript in `filea.php` is loaded and runs, the HTML in `fileb.php` doesn't exist so the JavaScript can't do anything with it. You might be able to use `.live()` or `.delegate()` to wire things up, otherwise you have to execute the JavaScript on the HTML that you `.load()` by hand using the callback:

```
$(stuff).load('fileb.php', function() {
    // The new HTML has been loaded into "stuff"
    // so you can run the JavaScript to bind whatever
    // it is that you're doing to the new HTML elements.
});
```

If what you're doing isn't just adding an event handler then `.live()` and `.delegate()` probably won't work and you'll have to use the callback on `.load()` as above.

Further reading:

- [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)
- [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
- [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)